# Schedule a post

Tags: discussion

Would being able to schedule a question / answer (or even a comment) be something worth having? What would the implications be? I'd like to know what the community thinks about this.

It's not yet ready for a [feature request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/feature-request/info), just an open discussion to see what we think about it.

Comment: Con: [Minus 100 points](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericgu/2004/01/12/minus-100-points/).

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom, interesting thought. It could've come with a bit more details and _stuff_, but interesting, nonetheless...

Comment: I can't see any upside... We already have plenty of post created that way (post and never interact on the site). Not sure why more of such posts would be useful.

Comment: One **shallow** 'upside' would be to schedule a question to be posted at 'rush hour' - that moment when people are more active. Of course, this could be a double edged sword, since the question could get lost among a bunch of others...

Comment: This question got 3 interactions and none about how I could make the post easier to understand (clear)

Comment: [Voting is different on Meta](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta).

Comment: one of the annoying things on SO is when a user posts a question then does not respond to comments for hours or days or weeks. This would make that even worse. Users should be encouraged to be active and involved - this would make people standoffish

Answer (score 3):

From what I understand, you essentially want [Boomerang](http://www.boomeranggmail.com/l/schedule-an-email.html), except for SE sites. While there are plenty of reasons why one might use Boomerang, none of them really apply to the Q&A format.

You should be available to provide clarifications on your posts right when they are posted. That's enough for me to not want this.

At best this would just be a lot of work to implement, and it would upstage more important things that I want more.

Comment: About the _"You should be available to provide clarifications on your posts right when they are posted."_, the android app always notifies me on updates for my posts. Of course it's a downside because you get tied to the app...

Comment: @FirstOne I imagine that some people would schedule it to post when they are asleep.

Comment: That's just slightly different from posting a question and having to leave (like going to sleep).. If you are available, you are available.

Comment: I do get your point, though, and I also think that it would open space for negligence.

Answer (score 1):

*My two cents..* This would probably bring more downs than ups. Here are some downs:

- People **forgetting** that they've scheduled something;
- **Outdated** schedules:

  - Updates that make the scheduled post **invalid**;
  - Scheduled posts that have pretty much the **same content** as other already posted stuff;
- **Delayed** responses;
- 'Unnecessary' bumps that don't add much;
- ...
- Negligence in a bunch of different ways...

---

An arguably interesting idea (not necessarily good), is to schedule a question to be posted at 'rush hour' - that moment when people are more active. The mobile app could be used by the OP to get notifications on responses / updates so they can provide quicker feedback. Of course, this could be a double edged sword, since the question could get lost among a bunch of others..

---

Again, even if *forcefully* considered good, the *not explicitly* bad point does not get any close to the negative ones.